# How to access Apache2 container working directory in order to change the content of default html?

Tags: apache, docker, docker-machine

I have installed apache2 container using docker as below

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name apache  httpd:2.4
```

apache server is running and I am able to see below screen.

[image: apache ok]

But how do I change the content of above screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get inside the image

```
docker exec -it apache bash
```

If bash is not there then use `sh`. After that you need to have a editor installed inside

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano

nano index.html
```

And then you can change the content

**Edit-1: Files in container**

To copy the files you the running container you need to do it like below

```
docker cp /home/ubuntu/docker-work/sample.html apache:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Comment: Great can you accept the answer clicking on the tick button below votes?

Comment: do you any idea about copying  local(host) html files onto container(apache) shared folder /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ ?

Comment: I tried this :  docker cp  /home/ubuntu/docker-work/sample.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
But not working